# Wordpress theme customization issue

Tags: wordpress, themes

I have install and active a theme in my wordpress website. And add some additional CSS to improve looking of webpage.after some time I installed and active a new theme and delete the old theme but the content and design of old theme is still exists on website which is mixing in new theme how to remove old theme design and content

Comment: quite very an uncommon situation, have you tried cleaning the browser cache?, are you working with child themes?, how (and where) did you add that additional CSS?

Answer (score 0):

You Can delete the old theme from

`wp-content/theme` folder   Manually

and remove the additional css that you have added for old theme